# What is the difference between using only async Task and Task?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

For example, the difference between this code

```
public Task<IList<NewsSentimentIndexes>> GetNewsSentimentIndexes(DateTime @from,
    DateTime to = new DateTime(), string grouping = "1h")
{
    var result = _conf.BasePath
        .AppendPathSegment("news-sentiment-indexes")
        .SetQueryParams(new
        {
            from = from.ToString("s"),
            to = to.ToString("s"),
            grouping
        });

    return result
       .GetStringAsync()
       .ContinueWith(Desereialize<IList<NewsSentimentIndexes>>);
}
```

and that

```
public async Task<IList<NewsSentimentIndexes>> GetNewsSentimentIndexes(DateTime @from,
    DateTime to = new DateTime(), string grouping = "1h")
{
    var result = _conf.BasePath
        .AppendPathSegment("news-sentiment-indexes")
        .SetQueryParams(new
        {
            from = from.ToString("s"),
            to = to.ToString("s"),
            grouping
        });

    var newsStr =  await result.GetStringAsync();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewsSentimentIndexes>(newsStr);
}
```

Which one is correct or faster working?
And just call this method need to await or just a task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `async` one is better. You should always prefer to use `await` instead of `ContinueWith`. I go into the details of [why `ContinueWith` is bad](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html) on my blog.

The semantic differences between these two implementations are due to two differences: whether or not `async` is used, and whether or not `ContinueWith` is used.

Removing `async` changes exception semantics. When `async` is used, any exceptions are caught (by the compiler-generated state machine) and placed on the returned task. Without `async`, exceptions are raised directly (synchronously). So, if `BasePath`, `AppendPathSegment`, `SetQueryParams`, or `GetStringAsync` throw (or return `null` or anything like that), then that exception would be raised synchronously rather than asynchronously, which could be confusing to callers.

Using `ContinueWith` changes execution semantics. In this case, `Deserialize` will be scheduled on `TaskScheduler.Current`. This dependence on the current `TaskScheduler` is one of the trickiest parts of `ContinueWith`.

Comment: Tell me please how to be a WaitAll and their continuation . It 's impossible to use the await

Comment: `Task.WaitAll(
_newsService.GetAll(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1), to: DateTime.Now)
                    .ContinueWith(ContinuationAction),
_tradingPairService.GetAllExchangeTradingPairAsync(ExchangeId, TradingPairId).ContinueWith(ContinuationAction),
             _companyTypesService.GetAll().ContinueWith(ContinuationAction) );`

Comment: I read your blog thank you, but you have to WaitAll example, with the same tasks.
With the continuation of the same

Comment: @GlebPatcia: In this case you should use `WhenAll` and not `WaitAll`. You can always use `await` instead of `ContinueWith`. Sometimes you just need to introduce a new method. Like `async Task GetAndProcessAsync(...) { await _newsService.GetAll(..); ContinuationAction(); }` which can then be used as `await Task.WhenAll(GetAndProcessAsync(..), ..);`

Comment: Thank you! now I understand

Answer (score 5):

Both methods returns same type: `Task`. But `async` method allows to use `await` keyword in his body. It informs compiler to generate state machine for `await` and its all. About async/await performance you can read [this post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx)

Comment: Yes, they are. Furthermore, you can use `await` with any method (async and not async).

Answer (score -3):

Async Task returns the object, while Task does not.

So you can do this with Async Task:

```
var yourTask = AsyncTask()
```

while you can do this with normal Task:

```
NormalTask().someFunction()
```